# The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'StoredProcedureReturn'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I write a stored procedure in which I have make JOIN and getting Data from Two tables.

I am getting Invigilator Name and also City name from JOIN in stored procedure but in Entity Framework Stored procedure is not running and Below exception is coming that

> Message   "The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'pts_dbnModel.GetInviglatorData_Result'. A member of the type,
>   'Name1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with
>   the same name."   string

```
select s.Name,s.contact ,c.Name ,s.frequency,s.cnic from zaid.invigilator s
INNER JOIN zaid.city c ON s.city=c.ID
INNER JOIN CompaignInvigilatorMapping m ON s.ID=m.InvigilatorId
INNER JOIN [hasnat.compaign] h ON m.CompaignId=h.ID where 
h.CompaignName=@CompName
```

Now the problem is on Name field . Because s.Name is from Invigilator Table and c.Name is from City table.

Answer (score 1):

use alias

```
select s.Name as invaigilatorName,s.contact ,c.Name as cityName ,s.frequency,s.cnic from zaid.invigilator s
INNER JOIN zaid.city c ON s.city=c.ID
INNER JOIN CompaignInvigilatorMapping m ON s.ID=m.InvigilatorId
INNER JOIN [hasnat.compaign] h ON m.CompaignId=h.ID where 
h.CompaignName=@CompName
```

Comment: From where I have to mark it as Accepted I cant give you upvote

Answer (score 1):

You have two table with the same columns name there is no problem with your select query as you have done before, if you don't qualified column names(like `s.Name,c.Name`) you will get exception as

> Ambiguous column name 'Name'.

but your problem is about `EF`, that error message means the result of your stored procedure do not contain a column named `Name1`, you have two option to resolve the problem.

1- Present `Name1` in your stored procedure by alias name like:

```
select s.Name as Name1,s.contact ,c.Name ,s.frequency,s.cnic from zaid.invigilator s
INNER JOIN zaid.city c ON s.city=c.ID
INNER JOIN CompaignInvigilatorMapping m ON s.ID=m.InvigilatorId
INNER JOIN [hasnat.compaign] h ON m.CompaignId=h.ID where 
h.CompaignName=@CompName
```

2- Or make your EF model and query to be compatible with output of your stored procedure (for example rename `Name1` to `Name` in `EF` model).

Your stored procedure don't have problem alone, but it should be compatible with your `EF` model or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks that worked because Zaynul also give same answer I call by making alias